# Disable the checkbox and select list using element_children

Tags: 7

Hi I am trying to disable all the form elements of the form. I am using this code to disable the form .

```
foreach (element_children($form) as $key) {  
  $form[$key]['#disabled'] = TRUE; 
    $form['#attributes'] = array('disabled' => TRUE);
    }
    drupal_set_message("Website is currently in read only mode. During this it is not possible to change site content", "warning");
}
```

It is working for textbox, radios and submit button but not for the select list and checkbox. What shall I do?

Answer (score 0):

In a word: recurse.

```
function _disable_self_and_descendants(&$el) {
  $el['#disabled'] = TRUE;

  foreach (element_children($el) as $key) {
    _disable_self_and_descendants($el[$key]);
  }
}

_disable_self_and_descendants($form);
```

Comment: this is not working for me. I tried. May be I am doing something wrong